# Why am I being told my mySQLi object is a 'non-object'?

Tags: mysqli, php

I'm trying to build a website using object-oriented functionality, and running into some issues.  The one that is currently vexing me is an error message that I can't solve:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in /home/rilbur5/public_html/tutor/login.php on line 41`

`function get_user_MYSQL(){
        return new mysqli($GLOBALS['db_host'],$GLOBALS['user_login'],$GLOBALS['user_password'],$GLOBALS['db_name']);
    }//will turn this into a singleton object later`

```
class User_Login{
    private $db_link;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $db_link=get_user_MYSQL();
    }

    public function bar($foo)
    {
        $foo=$db_link->real_escape_string($foo);
    }
}
```

I've inserted an echo statement into the constructor, and it IS being called.  I've tested the get_user function, and it works elsewhere -- in fact, I used an echo statement that showed that the data was, in fact, being properly escaped when I used real_escape_string on an object produced by the get_user functions.  So why is the combination not producing a mySQLi function that will do the necessary work?

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `get_user_MYSQL()` to make sure it's returning an object?

Comment: While a good point -- I've engaged in unintentional happy path programming here -- it does in fact return a value.  A better question would be how do I redesign the class to handle that check... a die function, or return nil and then check in the new statement that it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `$this->db_link`, since you're trying to access the MySQLi object within the class.

Comment: Well, now I just feel silly -- consider your answer accepted, as soon as the website will let me accept it.